# What are recommended patterns to localize a dynamically built phrase?

Tags: localization, globalization, phrase

Given a phrase that is dynamically constructed with portions present or removed based on parameters, what are some possible solutions for supporting localization?  For example, consider the following two phrases with bold parts that represent dynamically inserted portions:

- The dog is **spotted**, has **a doghouse** and is **chasing a ball**.
- The dog is **white**, and is **running in circles**.

For English, this can be solved by simply concatenating the phrase portions or perhaps having a few token-filled strings in a resource file that can be selected based on parameters.  But these solutions won't work or get ugly quickly once you need to localize for other languages or have more parameters.  In the example above, assuming that the dog appearance is the only portion always present, a localized resource implementation might consist of the following resource strings:

```
 AppearanceOnly:    The dog is %appearance%.
 ActivityOnly:      The dog is %appearance% and is %activity%.
 AssessoryOnly:     The dog is %appearance% and has %accessory%.
 AccessoryActivity: The dog is %appearance%, has %accessory% and is %activity%.
```

While this works, the required number of strings grows exponentially depending upon the number of parameters.

Been searching far and wide for best practices that might help me with this challenge.  The only solution I *have* found is to simply reword the phrase—but you lose the natural sentence structure, which I really don't want to do:

- Dog: **spotted**, **doghouse**, **chasing ball**

Suggestions, links, thoughts, examples, or "You're crazy, just reword it!" feedback is welcome :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to divide the sentence to separate sentences, like “The dog is spotted. The dog has a doghouse. The dog is chasing a ball.” This may look boring, but if you would replace all occurrences of “the dog” except the first one, you have a serious pronoun problem. In many languages, the pronoun to be used would depend on the noun it refers to. (Even in English, it is not quite clear whether a dog is he, she, or it.)

The reason for separation is that different languages have different verb systems. For example, in Russian, you cannot really combine the three sentences into one sentence that has three verbs sharing a subject. (In Russian, you don’t use the verb “to be” in present tense – instead, you would just say the equivalent of “Dog – spotted”, and there is no verb corresponding to “to have” – instead, you use the equivalent of “at dog doghouse”. Finnish is similar with respect to “to have”. Such issues are sometimes handled, in “forced” localizations, by using a word that corresponds to “to possess” or “to own”, but the result is odd-looking, to put it mildly.)

Moreover, languages have different natural orders for subject, verb, and object. Your initial approach implicitly postulates a SVO order. You should not assume that the normal, unmarked word order always starts with the subject. Instead of using sentence patterns like "%subject% %copula% %appearance% (where %copula% is “is”, “are”, or “am” in English), you would need to call a function with two parameters, subject and appearance, returning a sentence that has a language-dependent copula, or no copula, and that has a word order determined by the rules of the language. Yes, it gets complicated; localization of generated statements gets rather complicated as soon as you deal with anything but structurally very similar languages.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and great information, Jukka.  My sample phrases are not probably the best example for what I'm trying to do (my need is more strict and follows a pattern), so I may need to clarify above.